# Is there a .net wrapper library for the urbanairship api?

Tags: .net, push-notification, urbanairship.com

It's not a particularly difficult library to write (see
[iphone push notification urbanairship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393725/iphone-push-notification-urbanairship)), but it is something that everyone interacting with UA's service will probably be writing. So, I'm wondering, does it exist yet? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try searching for C# instead of .NET. For instance: 
http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2010/12/sending-json-push-notification-messages-to-urban-airship-service-with-c.html

came from:
http://www.google.ca/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=urban+airship+c%23&qscrl=1

There's also already a good thread on SO:
[iphone push notification urbanairship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393725/iphone-push-notification-urbanairship)

But you're right, doesn't seem like there's a completed or official library for .NET. Maybe because it's pretty easy to implement....

Answer (score 2):

I started my own project to do this

https://github.com/SimonCropp/UrbanBlimp

Answer (score 2):

There's also one I wrote called UrbanAirSharp

https://github.com/JeffGos/urbanairsharp

Comment: Used it, thanks jeffG for this very well structured SDK. Only had to add the NamedUser audience type and I was running!

Comment: :) Glad you found it useful.