# how to send push JSON to urban airship server using api

Tags: android, sencha-touch, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am using urban airship for sending push notification, i finished all configuration in my app and i can send notification from urban airship website.

Now i have to request urban airship api for sending push notification (using this " https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/") URL and i have send json like this

```
{
    "apids": [
        "some APID",
        "another APID"
    ],
    "aliases": ["my_alias"],
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
    "android": {
         "alert": "Hello from Urban Airship!",
         "extra": {"a_key":"a_value"}
    }
}
```

i want to send push notification for single device, i have to do this using APID, isn't it?.

what is APID?

**EDIT**

This groovy push request code

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.0' )
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

       def http = new HTTPBuilder('https://go.urbanairship.com')
       http.request( POST ) {
         uri.path = '/api/push/'
         body = [android: 'alert: You have reply', apids: 'some apid']
         requestContentType = ContentType.JSON

         response.success = { resp ->
           println "Success! ${resp.status}"
         }
       }
```

But it's not working?

Comment: define "i think this APID not working after some time" (define "not working", define "i think", define "some time". Also, what do you mean "what is the request format" ? isn't it, like, a simple post ?

Comment: i want to send push notification for single device,i have to do this using APID, isn't it?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**APID will generate when a device trying to register(unique id for every device), using APID we can send push notification to particular device.**

how to send request to Urban airship is explained here,
[Java code for sending request to urban airship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908476/send-push-via-urban-airship-using-their-web-service-java)